# Is there any scripts available to import multiple csv files and stitch the data in terms of dates and export it to n excel file

Tags: python, numpy, csv, matplotlib

I want to write a python script to plot a graph from daily data ( temperature, humidity vs time (15 mins interval) stored in multiple csv files (daily basis). I want to read the entire monthly data (30 csv files), filter the columns and store the entire monthly data in a single file, in terms of Time and date to plot the graph for a month.

This is the code I use to open, filter and plot the graph from a single csv file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/home/hebin/Documents/PV/Mitsui",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print(root.filename)
f = open(root.filename)
df= pd.read_csv(root.filename)
df.drop([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],inplace=True)
df_new = df.rename(columns={'Location': 'Date', 'Unnamed: 1':'Time','testo 160 IAQ_51602514 [°C]':'Temperature [°C]','testo 160 IAQ_51602514 [%RH]':'Relative Humidity[%RH]'},
index={'ONE': 'one','ONE': 'one','ONE': 'one','ONE': 'one'})
%matplotlib inline
plt.figure(figsize=(100,50))
fig, Ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,20))
Ax2 = Ax1.twinx()
Ax3 = Ax1.twinx()
Ax1.plot('Time', 'Temperature [°C]', data=df_new, linewidth=2, color='g' )
Ax2.plot('Time', 'Relative Humidity[%RH]', data=df_new,linewidth=2,color='b')
Ax1.grid(True)
Ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
Ax1.set_ylabel('Temperature [°C]', color='g')
Ax2.set_ylabel('Relative Humidity[%RH]', color='b')
```

This the image of my data
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHeug.png)

actual data is starting from the 9th row. Each data starts from 12:00 am to 12:00 am next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read all your .csv files and combine them in one .csv or .xlsx file by below code: (as you did not mention which type of filtering do you need I cannot provide any solution for that part):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv
maxInt = sys.maxsize

while True:
# decrease the maxInt value by factor 10
# as long as the OverflowError occurs.

try:
    csv.field_size_limit(maxInt)
    break
except OverflowError:
    maxInt = int(maxInt / 10)

# Define the path including all csv files
os.chdir(os.path.abspath("C:\Data"))

extension = 'csv'
files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.csv'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list (by skiprows, you can identify how many rows 
#should be discarded during reading files)
combined_files = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=8) for f in files],
                           axis=0,
                           ignore_index=True,
                           sort=False)

#Then you can filter your columns and after that export as a single excel file
combined_files.to_excel("C:\Data\combined_files.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried the above code. I want to filter the data before exporting it to the Excel. Like delete the first 8 rows of every csv file and save it to excel. I tried '''pd. drop" but it drops only the fort 8 rows of the first cav file. If you can help me to drop the rows of every csv file would be very helpful

Comment: @hebin In order to filter the 8 first rows of every .csv files, you need to add skiprows = 8  when you want to read files through pd.read_csv(f,skiprows=8). I have already edited the above code. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your data, it is hard to help with the exact details, but this should help load the files and then you will be in a good place to plot. Please let me know if this is what you are thinking of.   You can used pandas and glob.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'INSERT_PATHHERE' # path to foler including all the files
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

allWeather= []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    allWeather.append(df)

df = pd.concat(allWeather, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```